# Python - Howto manage a list of threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using **Python 2.7.6** and the **threading module**.

I am fairly new to python threading. I am trying to write a program to read files from a filesystem and store some hashes in my database. That are a lot of files and I would like to do it in threads. Like one thread for every folder that starts with a, one thread for every folder that starts with b. Since I want to use a database connection in the threads I don't want to generate 26 threads at once. So I would like to have 10 threads running and always if one of them finishes I want to start a new thread.

- The main program should hold a list of threads with a specified max
  amount of threads (e.g. 10)
- The main program should start 10 threads
- The main program should be notified when one thread finished
- If a thread is finished start a new one
- And so on ... until the job is done and every thread is finished

I am not quite sure how the main program has to look like. How can I manage this list of threads without a big overhead?

Comment: Take a look at process/thread pools. That's what you want to use: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for ... would like to rate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to indicate you that python doesn't manage well multi-threading : As you might know (or not) python comes with a Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), that doesn't allow real concurrency : Indeed, only one thread will execute at a time. (However you will not see the execution as a sequential one, thanks to the process scheduler of your machine)

Take a look here for more information : http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf

That said, if you still want to do it this way, take a look at semaphores : every thread will have to acquire it, and if you initialize this lock to 10, only 10 thread at a time will be able to acquire it.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Semaphore

Hope it helps

Comment: sounds great ... even if you have like 4 cores, only one is used?

Comment: Yes indeed, memory structure in Python are not Thread-Safe sadly... You can still look on other implementation of python that try to ensure real concurrency : Jython for exemple, doesn't seem to have a GIL (you may want to check that)

Comment: I used this some time ago to bypass the GIL : it is a new implementation that try to make "real concurrency" http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/stm.html

Comment: It is true that threads in Python will only use one CPU core and therefor do not speed up CPU-bound tasks. However, it sounds like your task is I/O-bound, so it will likely benefit from threads, as the GIL is released on I/O (see page 10 of the linked presentation). For CPU-bound tasks, you might be able to use multiprocessing instead of multithreading.